# Fetching data and conditional rendering with React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, use-effect

I'm building a MERN stack app that fetches data about college classes and render it in a table. The `CoursesTable.js` component looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-materialize';
import axios from 'axios';

const CoursesTable = () => {

  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const coursesData = await axios.get('http://localhost:8001/')
      setCourses(coursesData.data)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="course-name">
            Name
          </th>
          <th data-field="course-prof">
            Prof.
          </th>
          <th data-field="course-code">
            Code
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
          courses.length >= 1
          ? courses.map(course => 
              <tr key={course._id}>
                <td>
                  {course.name}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {course.prof}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {course.code}
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          : <tr>
              <td>There is no course</td>
            </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default CoursesTable;
```

I use conditional rendering so that if `courses` is empty, a message that goes like *There is no course* is displayed. When the array is full, the data is rendered in table rows.

My issue is: when `courses` is full and `CoursesTable.js` is rendered, the *There is no course* message always comes up for just a few milliseconds before being replaced with the data.

How can I fix this? Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a conditional check in place, e.g.:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-materialize';
import axios from 'axios';

const CoursesTable = () => {

  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const coursesData = await axios.get('http://localhost:8001/')
      setCourses(coursesData.data)
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
  if(isLoading) { return <div> Loading ... </div> };
  return (
    <Table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="course-name">
            Name
          </th>
          <th data-field="course-prof">
            Prof.
          </th>
          <th data-field="course-code">
            Code
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
          courses.length >= 1
          ? courses.map(course => 
              <tr key={course._id}>
                <td>
                  {course.name}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {course.prof}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {course.code}
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          : <tr>
              <td>There is no course</td>
            </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default CoursesTable;
```

Comment: Thanks! Nothing wrong with the way I use useEffect then?

Comment: I don't think so. Using an `async` function in `useEffect` is a common thing to get wrong, but the way you handle this here is correct. Looks good to me!

Comment: You are doing everything correctly. However, since you fetch your data asynchronously there is a small window of time before it returns. The answer above is, in my opinion, the best way to handle these situations. Although, I would use a ternary operator for returning instead of doing return two times. (but thats completely on your preference).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question guys! It solved my problem.